Document Library Challenges
Each week I create and publish a new Sharepoint page for our weekly team newsletter. I save all of these pages into a specific document library on Sharepoint. I created a Newsletter archive view for the team which displays all the newsletters published so far. In this view, I added a column called "Content" and we add a few lines describing what is included within each of the weekly newsletters.
When I look at the newsletter archive, it looks perfect. I can see the newsletters and I can see the "content". This is how it appears for me:

However, when my site visitors look at this same page, they see the newsletters but do not see the updated "Content" information. It seems like a permissions issue but visitors have "Read" permission which should allow them to view the document library and related columns.
Oddly, they are able to see 1 column filled out but cannot see the others. This is how it appears for them:

What am I doing wrong?

care to post a screenshot? I'm having trouble visualising what you see and others don't. Don't they see the column at all or is the column blank? You can edit the screenshot to mask confidential data with black boxes, but make sure we can see what we're dealing with, i.e. web part on a page? or list view? Please edit your question to post that additional info. do not put it in a comment. You can post a comment when you have updated your question, then we will be notified.

Does the column contain custom formatting? Do they see the column but its empty? Or is the column not visible?

Edited, thank you!

Do you have content approval and draft item security on for the library? If so, is the file approved? Just a thought.

Is the content column a multi line field with append enabled? In that case users should have permissions to view all versions.

If this is helpful:
Require content approval for submitted items is set to NO

If this is helpful:
Require content approval for submitted items is set to NO
Create a version each time you edit a file in this document library is set to Create major and minor (draft) versions
and Draft Item security is set to Only user who can edit items.
